# How to pass predictions from tunRanger to confusion matrix?

Tags: r, parameters, random-forest

I am trying to predict binary outcome (class1 and class2) by tuneRanger function in r as

```
library(mlr)
    library(tuneRanger)
    task = makeClassifTask(data = train, target = "outcome")
    estimateTimeTuneRanger(task)

    res = tuneRanger(task, measure = list(multiclass.brier), 
                     num.trees = 1000,num.threads = 8, iters = 70)
    a<-predict(res$model, newdata = test)
```

My question is how to get confusion matrix after this? Predict gives me probabilities and if I use

```
confusionMatrix(a, test$outcome, positive = 'Class2')
```

I will have the error: Error: `data` and `reference` should be factors with the same levels.
Do I need to define another random forest model and use the optimal parameters from tuneRanger?

In advance thank you for your attention

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and I used:

```
a<-predict(res$model**$model.learner**, newdata = test)
```

From there you can get `a$predictions` that you could use to get the confussion matrix.